# how to print glossary from separate file

Tags: glossaries

I'm having some trouble getting my glossary to print. I have followed examples here and on Overleaf.com, but somehow it still won't print.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry} % Page margins
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book
% Font Settings
\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font together with math symbols from the Symbol, Chancery and Computer Modern fonts
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Definitions of new commands
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\cvx}{convex}
% glossary
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries} 
\input{glossary}
\makeglossaries
\title{Glossary}
\begin{document}



\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

My glossary.tex file looks like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{domain-knowledge}{%
  name={domain knowledge},%
  description={valid knowledge used to refer to an area of human endeavour, an autonomous computer activity, or other specialized discipline}}

\newacronym{tla}{TLA}{Three Letter Acronym}

\newglossaryentry{Faith}
{%
   name={faith},%
   description={"Unflinching trust in something sublime."\cite{Bg.}Verse 2.41}}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you have to *use* a glossary entry in your document, but you have to run an external tool to get the entries sorted out.

Comment: Ugh, point taken and problem solved. You do have to "use" a glossary entry in order for it to appear in the "Glossary".